# Unity animation rotations are doing something wrong?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

When using the Unity timeline to create an animation or by using the animator itself, I am unable to properly rotate an object. 
Whenever I do rotate it, it will usually go something as follows: From 0 -> 20 = 0, -132, 67, -89 and then 20.

I have tried to manually set the rotation values, doing this does help, but this means that I will have to do everything manually which is a crap ton of work. I also did make an animation yesterday with the timeline animation with no problems at all, in the morning there were the same problems and I have no clue how it suddenly worked.

I have also tried selecting rotation in the animation window and changing Euler to Euler (Quaternion) or Quaternion itself. This doesn't work, it will only have a less spinning outcome.

I would like to know if anyone has any solutions for this problem. I am using Unity version: 2018.3.5f1.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: You should use: [Transform.Rotate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)

Comment: Im not using code for it, I'm just using Unity's integrated animation editor

Comment: So try using the curve instead

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your integrated animation editor?

Comment: Wait a sec i'm launch it

Comment: *"Im not using code for it, I'm just using Unity's integrated animation editor"* then this question is for the [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site of the network

Comment: @Cid +1 you are right but still we can answer here for next user it's easier to find than gamdev :)

Answer (score -1):

You should use curve instead, it is more precise:

[image: Unity Curve editor]